# How to rsync a folder when the folder path contains special chars?

Tags: rsync

I would like to rsync a folder but have some problems doing so due to the fact that the folder's path contains some special chars. My rsync command uses to look like this:

```
rsync -Pavzbe ssh user@server.com:"/home/user/Bücher" /home/user/
```

I get the following message:

```
Unexpected remote arg: user@server.com:/home/gast/B\\#303\#274cher
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1232) [sender=3.0.8]
```

I tried the following command instead but got the same result

```
rsync -Pavzbe --iconv=CP1250,UTF-8 ssh user@server.com:"/home/user/Bücher" /home/user/
```

Who can help?

Comment: Try with `--iconv=.` or `--iconv=utf8,cp1250`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try one of:

1. Making a symlink to the folder, and rsync that folder (of course with a "follow symlinks" option on the command line).
2. Syncing the folder /home/user instead, and use filters to make sure I only got what I wanted.
3. Rename the unfortunate folder.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-s` to `rsync` command (together with `--iconv`) should do the trick.

```
rsync -Pavzbe -s --iconv=CP1250,UTF-8 ssh user@server.com:"/home/user/Bücher" /home/user/
```